# Convert generic types to object

Tags: java, generics

Let's say I have a function which deals which returns and accepts generic type. The function may look like this

```
public T call(T t) {
    Log.v(FILE_NAME, "t: " + t.toString());
    return null;
}
```

Let's say if the code detected that t.toString() looks like

```
{label1=5148.000, label2=8363.000, label3=715.000}
```

Is there any way I can convert t to an object which we can easily manipulate it's content? By manipulating, I mean we can easily, for example change label1, label2 and label3 value to something else, and return the modified t.

Just in case, in the example above, the parameter t that passed was of type `Map<String,String>`.

Update:

1. Yes, I'm implementing `Callable<T>`.
2. In the future, I might supply other type of arguments, and not just `Map<String,String>`.

Comment: No you can't, because `Object` doesn't has such fields. Either you know the type of objects you like to pass as `t` to provide a bound for `T` or you can't change its field. (You could also do some nasty stuff with reflection, but ... don't think about it)

Comment: @Tom, what if I know the type of object that I pass as t? Is there any way I can convert t to the object? In this case, the object is Map<String,String>

Comment: @imin if it's always a `Map`, why are you using generics? If it's not always a `Map` then your argument falls down.

Comment: If you know the type and you want to "convert" it in that method, then why do you use generics, instead of `public void call(Map<String,String> t) {`?

Comment: @Tom: judging from the message signature, my guess is that OP is implementing Callable<T>.

Comment: @JanusVarmarken nope. [`Callable<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) _supplies_ `T` - it does not consume.

Comment: In any case, never rely on `toString` to provide a full description of an object. It is merely a human-readable format that is subject to change, and doesn't necessarily include all the necessary data.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: Correct, apparently it's getting late here. Sorry about that folks, please disregard my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm note entirely sure what you're asking for. If you know that `t` will always be of type `Map<String, String>`, you can simply cast it:

```
Map<String, String> myMap = (Map<String, String>) t;
```

Comment: This seems like a XY problem to me. An unsafe cast it rarely the solution to anything - especially a the beginner level.

Comment: @imin Easy to risk a `ClassCastException`, yes.

Comment: anyway in the future since I might pass different type, I might need to implement a function which tries to determine the data type, based on the pattern of t.toString()

Comment: You should NOT determine the type of an object based on what it returns from toString. See hotzst's answer for determining an object's type during runtime.

Comment: @imin that's a terrible idea on top of a terrible idea. You need to describe the problem you are trying to solve, not some subset of the solution.

Comment: Opps.. thanks for the heads up. Just refreshed and viewed hotzst answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to have the method really generic and have some special handling for some well known parameters you can have something like this:

```
if (t instanceof Map) {
    // do something here
}
```